# jQuery UI Dialog Spacebar Capture

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Space bar not working in form fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1987439/space-bar-not-working-in-form-fields)

Has anyone run into an issue with jQuery UI Dialog where it captures the spacebar key, and moves the form about 20 px down the screen?

I have a form in a dialog, and it just started occurring. I was working with disabling some buttons, but I commented out that code and it still is doing it. Thanks.

Comment: After looking again I noticed the spacebar is going to a thumbnail navigation for gallerific even though focus is on the input box of the dialog.

I am going to revert some htmlspecialchar() escapes I made earlier and see if that was interfering with the javascript.

Comment: I got it. Answer's here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1987439/space-bar-not-working-in-form-fields

Comment: Answer is here concerning issue with spacebar and jquery UI:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1987439/space-bar-not-working-in-form-fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering concerning this issue with the spacebar input and jqueryUI is here:

[Space bar not working in form fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1987439/space-bar-not-working-in-form-fields)