# HTML form doesnt allow spaces on inputs

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have an HTML form loaded in via ajax to a lightbox.

You can see the behaviour on the homepage of http://www.powerbuy.com.au/

In the bottom right of the page there is a Link 'Let us negotiate a deal for you' Clicking this creates a lightbox and loads the form.

The issue is that you cannot put in spaces to any of the fields, it appears to be accepting any other characters, numbers and symbols, but not spaces.

I have looked through the code for any keyCode in the JS, but I cant find anything related to spaces.

Can you replicate the issue? Can you tell me what is going on?

Comment: take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1987439/space-bar-not-working-in-form-fields) SO question.

Comment: @sixfive is this your website?

Comment: I see some javascript replacing strings with regex, not sure what it does exactly but you should check it. Could you put up some code?

Comment: @ExplosionPills it is my clients site.

Comment: ok so I had a look through the post from @mumble. My clues I think are related to keyCode and charCode in the JS. We use jquery 1.7.1, shadowbox 3.0.3 and jquery UI. I cant find any reference in the shadowbox js that looks at keyCode or charCode. What next? I don't really have any code, it uses the std call to open up the content of the url via ajax into the shadowbox. You can take a look through the http://www.powerbuy.com.au/scripts/cms-fe.js that is all the JS, excluding shadowbox.

Comment: I have fixed this now by converting the load from ajax to iframe, and we seem to have now a form that is unencumbered. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cause unknown: 
Solved by converting lightbox popup from ajax load to iframe.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply write below code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("#id").keydown(function(event) {
    if(event.shiftKey)
    {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
    if (event.keyCode == 32)    {
        event.preventDefault();
    }

    });
});
```

"id" is your textfield "id" attribute value.

Comment: I couldn't get this to work as the form is loaded by ajax, and thus it doesn't hook up the event (or so it appears).

Answer (score 0):

You can fix it by setting `enableKeys : false` as following:

```
Shadowbox.open({
  title      : "Nouvel Addressee",
  content    : $("addressee-lightbox-wrapper").innerHTML,
  player     : "html",
  width      : 920,
  height     : 540,
  enableKeys : false,
  options    : {
    onFinish: function() {
      Event.addBehavior.reload();
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score -2):

I had similar problem. Found out, it has something with 'enableKeys' option.

There is more ways to set this option, but for some reason just this one worked for me:

```
Shadowbox.init({

skipsetup: true,
enableKeys: false   

});
```

Here are some other solutions mentioned http://shadowbox.1309102.n2.nabble.com/Can-t-add-space-in-text-input-td4518072.html

Comment: Please include relevant information from links in the body of the answer. Links may die/rot/move or otherwise become unavailable.