# WordPress search form doesn't allow spaces between words

Tags: php, wordpress, search, input

I'm building a theme in WordPress, which is outputting a search form in two different styles -- one on the homepage and one on other pages.

Both of them use the get_search_form() WordPress function, and both output identical HTML where they are called. For the non-frontpage version it works exactly as expected, but for the frontpage, while it renders the same HTML, it doesn't allow spaces.

I want the website user to be able to uses spaces on both forms.

**PHP:**

```
<?php 
    if ( is_front_page() ) {
?>

    <div class="hero-search full-width ">
        <div class="hero-searchbox">
            <?php 
                get_search_form(); 
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>

<?php 
    } else {
?>

<div class="container-fluid ">
    <div class="secondary-header">
        <?php 
            echo breadcrumbs(); 
        ?>
            <div class="breadcrumbs-search">
                <?php
                    get_search_form(); 
                ?>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>

<?php
    } // is_front_page
?>
```

**Output HTML frontpage:**

```
<div class="hero-search full-width ">
    <div class="hero-searchbox">
        <form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" class="searchform" action="http://it-connect.local/">
            <div>
                <label class="screen-reader-text" for="s">Search for:</label>
                <input type="text" value="" name="s" id="s" placeholder="Search for:" autocomplete="off">
                <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Output HMLT non-frontpage**

```
<div class="breadcrumbs-search">
    <form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" class="searchform" action="http://it-connect.local/" _lpchecked="1">
        <div>
            <label class="screen-reader-text" for="s">Search IT Connect for:</label>
            <input type="text" value="" name="s" id="s" placeholder="Search IT Connect for:" autocomplete="off">
            <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search">
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

**searchform.php code:**

```
<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" class="searchform" action="<?php echo set_url_scheme( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">
    <div>
        <label class="screen-reader-text" for="s">Search for:</label>
        <input type="text" value="" name="s" id="s" placeholder="Search for:" autocomplete="off">
        <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search">
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Are you using an jQuery plugins?

Comment: jQuery is being used, but no plugins for it.

Comment: This might be relevant ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14472768/html-form-doesnt-allow-spaces-on-inputs